# Best cross-platform development tool

Tags: windows, macos, cross-platform, development-environment

I am looking to develop a background app for MacOS and Windows (desktop, not mobile) that is mainly doing socket communication with a php server, and some basic gfx display. What cross-platform development tool could I use ?

Comment: You might want to check out Xojo, which can create native cross-platform apps for Windows, OS X and Linux from a single code base. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best - is somewhat subjective.....

If you are a .Net C# or VB.net coder I would recommend you take a look at c# visual studio on Windows and mono on Mac or their commercial offering Xamarin.Mac ( which you may not actually need as straight mono on mac might be fine.)

Windows will then be totally native and the Mac will be cross platform but by using mono you can get something which no one can tell was developed using a cross platform tool by looking at the resultant app.

[www.xamarin.com - commercial](http://xamarin.com)

[Mono Project - open source](http://www.mono-project.com/)

Comment: The best cross-platform framework, as many soundly think, is Qt (Trolltech/Nokia/Digia).

Comment: not for c# developers!